# ruby on rails, rails admin fieldset behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-admin

I working as intern for a webapp, they are using ruby on rails v4.2 and ruby v2.0.0, and rails admin v0.6.8.

There is a problem in rails admin that arrived since Friday, after a commit, do I look on github each diff in each commit, and the problem seems to come from the gemfile and gemfile.lock where thos changes happened :

[image]

[image]

And here is an image of the problem in the admin (I have to scroll on the right to see the field)

[image]

[image]

I try to update my gemfile after come back to `gem 'tinymce-rails', "~> 4.5.3"` instead of `gem 'tinymce-rails', "~> 4.5.5"`

But I have this error :

```
    Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Does anyone know which gem interact with rails admin ? and how could I fix the issue with nokogiri and tinymce-rails ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can fix the `nokogiri` gem issue by upgrading to Ruby v2.1.0 or above.

Comment: @BrandonCordell thank you for your answer, what If I can't upgrade my ruby version ? I have to stay in v2.0.0

Comment: You can use gem dependency -r rails_admin to see all gems rails admin depends on directly or indirectly